# Get n (part of) objects from a list of objects, starting from n index

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a list of n objects. I want to grab a maximum of n items (-n previous items and n + next items), starting from the selected index. I want a method for this, in which I provide the list with certain parameters.

How can I achieve this in C#?

**First example:**
int selectedIndex = 5
int itemsToTake = 4 (2 previous and 2 next)
Returned list = 3-4-5-6-7

**Second example:**
int selectedIndex = 1
int itemsToTake = 4 (take 1 previous and 3 next, because list starts with 0)
Returned list = 0-1-2-3-4

I have already tried a combination of list.skip().take(), only that didn't go so well.

**Example:**

```
nextIndex = nextIndex - prevIndex + 1;
return List.Skip (prevIndex) .Take (nextIndex) .ToList ();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inefficient but visually aesthetic way of doing it:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Nearby<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
    int selectedIndex, int itemsToTake)
{
    var left = source.Take(selectedIndex).Reverse().Take(itemsToTake / 2).Reverse();
    var middle = source.ElementAt(selectedIndex);
    var right = source.Skip(selectedIndex).Skip(1).Take(itemsToTake / 2);
    return left.Append(middle).Concat(right);
}
```

Usage example:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(0, 10);
Console.WriteLine($"Result: {String.Join(", ", source.Nearby(5, 5))}");
```

Output:

> Result: 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Answer (score 1):

Skip + Take should work fine, try this:

```
int firstIndex = selectedIndex - itemsToTake / 2;
firstIndex = firstIndex < 0 ? 0 : firstIndex;
return list.Skip(firstIndex).Take(itemsToTake);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the list contains enough elements:

```
if(itemsToTake  + 1 > List.Count)
    return List.ToList(); //copy the list
```

The first index you want to take is (not considering sequence borders):

```
var firstIndex = selectedIndex - itemsToTake  / 2;
```

The corresponding last index would be `firstIndex + n`.

Then, make sure that the range is valid

```
if(firstIndex < 0) 
    firstIndex = 0;
if(firstIndex + nitemsToTake >= List.Count)
    firstIndex = List.Count - 1 - itemsToTake ;
```

And finally do as you tried:

```
return List.Skip(firstIndex).Take(itemsToTake  + 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the special case of when `selectedIndex - itemsToTake / 2` is less than 0:

```
public static List<T> Take<T>(this List<T> list, int selectedIndex, int itemsToTake) {
    if (selectedIndex - n / 2  < 0) {
        return list.Take(itemsToTake + 1).ToList();
    }
    return list.Skip(selectedIndex - itemsToTake / 2).Take(itemsToTake +1).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Nearby<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int selectedIndex, int itemsToTake)
{
  itemsToTake = ((itemsToTake/2)*2)+1;
  Queue<T> queue = new Queue<T>();
  bool foundItem = false;
  int afterItemCount = 0;
  int recommendedAfterItemCount = itemsToTake/2;
  foreach(var pair in source.Select((t, i) => new {t, i}))
  {
    T t = pair.t;
    int i = pair.i;

    queue.Enqueue(t);
    if (itemsToTake < queue.Count) queue.Dequeue();

    if (i == selectedIndex) foundItem = true;
    else if (foundItem) afterItemCount += 1;

    bool enoughItems = queue.Count == itemsToTake;
    bool enoughAfterItems = recommendedAfterItemCount <= afterItemCount;
    if (enoughItems && enoughAfterItems) break;

  }
  foreach(T t in queue)
  {
    yield return t;
  }
}
```